# Which conditional is correct? "If I were/was/am to succeed..."

Tags: conditionals

> - If I were to succeed, I would have to toil a lot.
> - If I was to succeed, I would have to toil a lot.
> - If I am to succeed, I would have to toil a lot.

Which of the above sentences is incorrect? And why?

Answer (score 1):

> If I were to succeed, I would have to toil a lot.

> If I was to succeed, I would have to toil a lot.

> If I am to succeed, I would have to toil a lot.

The 1st example is in subjunctive mood.  It expresses something desired or imagined, or events not certain to happen.

The 2nd example is in the 2nd conditional, expressing something unlikely to happen.

The 3rd example is unusual. Using 'will' is better, and the sentence will then be in 1st conditional.

I add here.

The 2nd one uses the second conditional, the form of which is explained below.

> conditional clause: if + past simple

> Main clause: modal verb with future-in-the-past meaning (should/would/might/could)

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if

Comment: I agree with most of what you said, but the second one sounds to me like it's either in past tense, or equivalent to the first one (with the slightly controversial but common use of "was" for the subjunctive). I'm not quite sure what distinction you're describing or where it came from.

Comment: I have edited my a answer.